# How do you work with a C++ function that returns a shared_ptr<T> when calling it from Rust over FFI?

Tags: c++, rust, shared-ptr, ffi

C++

```cpp
shared_ptr<Foo> create_foo();
```

Rust

```rust
extern "C" {
    pub fn create_foo() -> ???;
}
```

Bindgen turns a `shared_ptr` into an opaque blob.

I can't just take the raw pointer because then the C++ code is unaware that I have a reference to `Foo` and might call its deconstructor.

Comment: Is it at all possible for you to design your code in such a way that either C++ or Rust owns the object and manages its lifetime?  You could trigger a callback when it is destroyed, to tell the "other" language to stop holding references to it.

Comment: You can also return a `new shared_ptr<Foo>(...)`... a bit like the double `Box` trick that is done sometimes from the Rust side.

Comment: Just to clarify this is an existing c++ library and I can't control how the pointer is created. I just get given a shared_ptr<Foo>  from a function.

Comment: So you want to be able to access to pointer inner type ?

Comment: @Stargateur yep but I don't want it to be free'd while I'm using it and if I just use the raw pointer I can't guarantee that.

Answer (score 4):

`std::shared_ptr` is a C++ class and a non-trivial type that can not be exported as is from a library — you need its definition in your target language to conform to the one in C++. To use FFI you need to provide your library functions with a simple C ABI (the C++ ABI is not stable and may change between compiler versions (as might Rust's ABI)) and I doubt that all of functions related to `std::shared_ptr` are such, so there is one more obstacle for that.

I'd suggest to return a raw C-pointer from your library instead and own it in Rust.

Even in C++, to load a C++ library you provide C-ABI functions (via `extern C`) to gain access to a pointer of your type and then you use it in C++ as how as you want.

So, a few points:

1. Return a raw C pointer from a function without name mangling so that we know its name and can link to it:

   ```cpp
   extern "C" Foo* create_foo();
   ```
2. Add a deleter which knows how to properly deallocate the object:

   ```cpp
   extern "C" void delete_foo(Foo *);
   ```
3. Let the library user (Rust) decide how to own it, for example, by `boxing` the value and using it with atomic reference counter via `std::sync::Arc` (as `std::shared_ptr` does):

   ```
   extern "C" {
       fn create_foo() -> *mut Foo;
       fn delete_foo(p: *mut Foo);
   }

   struct MyFoo {
       raw: *mut Foo,
   }

   impl MyFoo {
       fn new() -> MyFoo {
           unsafe { MyFoo { raw: create_foo() } }
       }
   }

   impl Drop for MyFoo {
       fn drop(&mut self) {
           unsafe {
               delete_foo(self.raw);
           }
       }
   }

   fn main() {
       use std::sync::Arc;

       let value = Arc::new(MyFoo::new());
       let another_value = value.clone();
       println!("Shared counter: {}", Arc::strong_count(&value));
   }
   ```
4. Let the C++ side forget about owning this pointer - you can't rely on it if it is used from outside the library and you give a raw pointer to it.

If you don't have any access to the library sources, can't do anything with it: the `std::shared_ptr` object will not release the pointer ever and we can't make it not to delete the pointer.

Comment: *"C++ abi is not stable"* -> "Is not specified"

Comment: That means it has not been stabilized I guess :)

Comment: It's a difference, because is has not been stabilized means (IMHO), that is about to stabilize and there is a standard for it. Not specified means there no specification at all.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. If I return a raw pointer how do I make sure c++ doesn't free the pointer?
`Foo * create_foo() {
shared_ptr<Foo> smart_p = lib::create_foo();
return smart_p.get();
}
`
Here smart_p's desctructor will be called at the end of the function and if its the last one it will free the pointer

Comment: @Tom good question, that's up to you. I would suggest creating a struct that contains the shared pointer and if rust decides to give up the struct (e.g. call `destroy_foo`) you will also drop the shared pointer.

Comment: @hellow Yeh that's what I'm thinking. Basically rust holds a struct that has the shared_ptr as an opaque_blob and returns it to c++ for destruction when I'm done with it. The downside is all work on the Foo must be done by passing it back to c++

Comment: @Tom I would say, that's worth a new question.

Comment: @E_net4 That's correct, thanks, I did not know it is so. What to use for owning a C pointer then?

Comment: @E_net4 At first, it is a link-only comment, at second, the `Box::from_raw` is used there, and third, it is about exporting Rust object to the outside, not import `C` pointers into `Rust` - there is a difference a little.

Comment: Again "stable C ABI", there is no such thing, the rule are the same than C++ "may change between compiler versions" because as C++ and Rust. The C ABI "Is not specified".

Comment: Right, sorry, I'm currently in a poor position to go into details. The C API has to expose a freeing function. In Rust land, we may then make a wrapper type that calls this function on  drop.

Comment: @Stargateur Okay, should I be more clear then, like to say that the only thing we need is to disable name mangling for the symbol? I was probably mistaken because name mangling is a part of ABI.

Comment: @E_net4 You're right, we have to use the same (de)allocation mechanism everywhere: new/delete, malloc/free and so on, because there may be different allocators we don't know about or at least other things like internal structure pointers which we will simply not deallocate using `free`.

So, it is still an open question what to use for wrapping C code then.

Comment: @E_net4 I have added my own version of code I'd write for this thing. Could you check it out please?

Comment: TL;DR: *How do you work with a C++ shared_ptr<T> in FFI?* — **you don't**.

Answer (score 2):

> I can't just take the raw pointer because then the C++ code is unaware that I have a reference to `Foo` and might calls it's deconstructor.

Yes and no. With your actual example. C++ will give ownership of the `shared_ptr` to the one who called `create_foo`, so C++ knows that there is still something that owns the pointer.

You need to add a `get` function that will get the value for you without losing ownership of the pointer, something like this:

```
extern "C" {
    std::shared_ptr<Foo> create_foo() {
        // do the thing
    }
    /* or maybe this
    std::shared_ptr<Foo> &&create_foo() {
        // do the thing
    }
    */

    Foo *get_foo(std::shared_ptr<Foo> &foo) {
        foo.get();
    }

    void destroy_foo(std::shared_ptr<Foo> foo) {
    }
    /* or maybe this
    void destroy_foo(std::shared_ptr<Foo> &&foo) {
    }
    */
}
```

Also `shared_ptr<Foo>` is not valid C, so I don't know if bindgen and C++ with accept this (probably a warning) but that is already present in your code.

On the Rust side, you could do this:

```
// must be generated by bindgen and this might create a lot of problems
// this need to be the same struct as the shared_ptr on the C++ side.
// if even one octet is not correct you will run into bugs
// BE SURE that bindgen don't implement Copy for this
struct shared_ptr<T>; 

struct Foo(i32);

extern "C" {
    fn create_foo() -> shared_ptr<Foo>;

    fn get_foo(foo: &shared_ptr<Foo>) -> *mut Foo;

    fn destroy_foo(foo: shared_ptr<Foo>);
}

fn main() {
    unsafe {
        let my_shared_foo = create_foo();
        let foo = get_foo(&my_shared_foo);
        (*foo).0;
        destroy_foo(my_shared_foo);
    }
}
```

Of course this is just an example, and nothing is really safe in any of this. And as I can't test, please let me know if I wrote something that doesn't work. `bindgen` should do the job.

Comment: I *think* that `std::shared_ptr<Foo> &&create_foo()` is wrong and makes no sense at all.

Comment: @E_net4 Yes I just create something that compile in Rust, but indeed this struct need to match the actual struct `std::shared_ptr` if not Rust can't move it correctly.

Comment: @hellow I not sure too, as we tell to rust to use C semantic, I suppose it doesn't but in this case `destroy_foo(std::shared_ptr<Foo> &&foo)` also don't make sense. Because rust will copy the value ? is this work ? I really don't know.

Comment: In you're example if we wrap the shared_ptr<Foo> in a struct and make it opaque then we can maintain ownership and still get the raw ptr eg:
`struct SmartPtr {`
`smart_ptr: opaque_blob[u64; 2],`
`raw_ptr: * mut Foo,`
`}`

Comment: @Tom That a bad idea to keep the raw pointer separate of shared_ptr, in my exemple I do it but I would advise you to create a structure that hide the raw pointer of shared_ptr.

Comment: @Stargateur if this is not done then what prevents c++ from calling the destructor at the end of get_foo?

Comment: @Tom It's a reference ? `get_foo()` do not own shared_ptr, it don't have the right to call the destructor. It's just I give you this temporally.

Answer (score -1):

You can return a pointer to a dynamically allocated `std::shared_ptr`

In the C++ side:

```cxx
shared_ptr<Foo> create_foo();
extern "C" void *rust_create_foo()
{
    shared_ptr<Foo> foo = create_foo();
    return static_cast<void*>(new shared_ptr<Foo>(foo));        
}
extern "C" void rust_delete_foo(void *ptr)
{
    shared_ptr<Foo> *foo = static_cast<shared_ptr<Foo>*>(ptr);
    delete foo;
}
```

And in the Rust side:

```rust
extern "C" {
    pub fn rust_create_foo() -> *const c_void;
    pub fn rust_delete_foo(foo: *const c_void);
}
```

If you fail to call `rust_delete_foo` then the dynamically allocated pointer will leak and so the object will never be deallocated.

Then, when you want to use the object, you will have to write wrapper functions that take that `void*`, do the cast and call the appropriate function.